# Kendo TreeView select function and event misbehaviour

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

For the ones who might spend hours trying to understand why they don't get the same behaviour from the select callback whether it is triggered by the select event or by the select method.

I couldn't understand why this was working perfectly when I picked an item manually, while there was no reaction if I was using the method. I have tried to trigger the event on the tree element, on the widget itself as it seemed it was not triggered at all.

```
select: function(e){
  var item = e.node;
  appui.f.post("admin/object_editor/obj/" +
    ( typeof(item.class) !== "undefined" ? "object" : "field" ) +
    "/" + item.id + "/" + item.uid, {partial:1}, $("#object_cfg_container"));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is triggered but returns an error from the first line when the select method is used.

Actually what happens is that the event is sent as the function's argument, in which you can find the node property, which is the newly selected object.

However when you use the select method the event argument doesn't have anymore the node property.

So maybe you found out that the select() method used without arguments returns the selected element.

But a new problem appears, this function will return the old selected item when launched during the event, while it will return the newly selected item if it's launched as a method...

My solution:

```
select: function(e){
  var item = e.node ? e.node : this.select(),  
      data = this.dataItem(item);
  ....
}
```